# Access GCP from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to telnet GCP instance from GAE. I have set instance-tag in the application running on GAE. And I can see the instance-tag in my the GAE UI as well.

```
network:
  instance_tag: app-tag
```

And I have also added the same as source tag in the firewall rule.

Anything I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "telnet GCP instance from GAE"?  What is the recipe / command set you are using and what errors or problems are being shown?

Comment: @Kolban I basically want to access an GCP instance from GAE. I have set the firewall rules where target is the network tag of GCP instance and source is the network tag which i have set in app.yaml file of application running in GAE. And I have allowed all ports in my firewall. So I am doing telnet to test the connection.

Comment: I never think of GAE (Google App Engine) as something one can login to but rather a platform to host application logic.  How are you logging into GAE in order to run telnet?   By GCP Instance in your question, I am assuming Google Compute Engine instance ... is that also correct?   Have you installed a telnet server on that machine?   What ingress and egress ports have you opened up?

Comment: @Kolban I'm using the cloud shell and trying to telnet Google Compute Engine instance from there. And I have telnet installed in the it. All ports are opened.

Comment: Which Telnet server did you install in your VM? Note: Telnet is ancient technology and is VERY insecure.